# read Cellvalue through a range, and write to a different range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a VBA scrip that check all cells between B2 and B60 for the text "Ja"    that's yes in Norwegian.
How can I make this a little bit simpler that making a "if" command for each cell?
I want it to, if the cell contains "ja"(yes) then write to colum D and the same number.
ie. B1,2,3,4,5 cotains "ja", I need it to take the previous cell value in D1.2,3,4,5 and add another digit to it +1.
If nothing is found in B(ie.false) it needs to write "NEI" in the current cell, and if "NEI" (no) is found in that cell it adds +1 to colum E

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim celltxt As String
Dim a As Variant
   If IsEmpty(Range("B2").Value) = True Then
    Cells(2, 2).Value = "NEI"
   End If
celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Text
If InStr(1, celltxt, "ja") Then
a = Cells(2, 1).Value
'write to cell
Cells(2, 4).Value = Cells(2, 4) + 1
Else
'antall Cw'er vedkommende IKKE har deltatt på
Cells(2, 5).Value = Cells(2, 5) + 1
End If
   If IsEmpty(Range("B3").Value) = True Then
    Cells(3, 2).Value = "NEI"
   End If
celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Text
If InStr(1, celltxt, "ja") Then
a = Cells(3, 1).Value
'write to cell
Cells(3, 4).Value = Cells(3, 4) + 1
Else
'antall Cw'er vedkommende IKKE har deltatt på
Cells(3, 5).Value = Cells(3, 5) + 1
End If


End Sub
Sub slettingALL()
    Range("D2:E55").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
Sub slettingdeltakelse()
    Range("B2:B60").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses a For Each loop and an IF THEN ELSE statement to check for the value "JA" in the range B2:B60.

If it finds "JA", it looks two columns to the right from the current i location, and adds "+1" to the value above it. If it finds nothing, it writes "NEI" to the current i location, and then moves three columns to the right and adds +1 to the value above it.

```
Sub Macro2()

For Each i In Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(60, 2))
    If i.Value = "JA" Then
        i.Offset(0, 2).Value = i.Offset(-1, 2).Value + 1
    Else
        i.Value = "NEI"
        i.Offset(0, 3).Value = i.Offset(-1, 3).Value + 1
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Please let me know if this code does not work for your purpose.

Comment: No worries, please don't forget to mark your chosen answer :)